# Need help deciphering a small stack trace: which kind of WS am I using?

Tags: java, web-services, axis, spring-ws

I'm trying to deploy an application and I've got a webservice that is unavailable.  By contacting the team responsible for the webservice, they're asking me if I'm using Axis or SpringWS to access their webservice (apparently in my case there's no other option).  Can this be determined from the following (partial) stack trace ?

Here's the Tomcat log I got:

> INFO main @ jaxws.PlatosJaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean - Retrieve of the wsdl informations.
>       Retrieving document at 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl'.
>       ERROR main @ utilities.WSDLAnalyzer - javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.xxxxxxxxxx?wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, judging by the info you posted you are using [GlassFish Metro](http://metro.java.net/).

Comment: +1 to all...  I accept your answer for, thanks to all your comments, I found that the code is indeed using GlassFish Metro.

Answer (score 2):

You're using some implementation of the JAX-WS API, but the error doesn't indicate which one.

Most likely it's the JAX-WS implementation that ships internally to Java6, but it could also be something like Apache CXF or Metro.  What's on your application's classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Are these two the only options?

[Google says](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22class+WSDLAnalyzer+%22) it might be something called Petals Service Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the ISMS-ALSA department of your company. And, by the way, you're not supposed to use Axis, nor Glassfish Metro!

p.s.: the best answer should rather be assigned to skaffman.